# Identify if an iOS In-App Purchase is a consumable or non-consumable?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I need a small help to know if what I propose in my iOS app is a consumable currency or not.

From the Apple Developer [In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) webpage:

> #### Consumable
>
> Users can purchase different types of consumables, such as lives or gems in a game, to further their progress through an app. Consumable in-app purchases are used once, are depleted, and can be purchased again.

Users can buy a currency that has a name, such as "bucks", for example: 100 bucks can be bought for $1.

User can receive or send this currency to another user. When desired, he can convert this virtual currency to money = for example: $1 for 95 bucks.

This currency is like a cryptocurrency and my app is not a game.

So is this currency a consumable or non-consumable? I need help with understanding to prevent my app from getting rejected.

Comment: Is there something else you're not including in your question?  It says consumables can only be used once and then depleted.  "Bucks" are used only once, right?  You don't get to use a buck and then still have it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please clarify how you are converting. From your description I understand, user can purchase 100 bucks for $1 and can get $1 back with 95 bucks. Is that so? What is the main functionality offered by your app? Or is exchanging bucks the main feature?

Comment: @fsb It's about the same as betting but not really. Anyway you can win or lose this currency yeah. Good question. So this is consumable right?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks to your edit and your comment, yea in practice you can bet this currency with your friend's.. I cannot say more ^^!

Comment: If it can be used for real-world purchases (which it can if it can be converted to cash), it can’t be bought as an in-app purchase. “3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.”

Comment: "Betting"? The US has some seriously draconian laws on 'betting, gambling & gaming'. you might fall foul of those long before anyone gets too 'consumable or not'.

Comment: @MikeScott I change the design of my currency in my app, now it's a real money like $, €. So now is it safe for me to use my own payment way?

Answer (score 1):

If an item can be used once and then is not available again, it is a consumable.

If an item can be reused over and over, it's a non-consumable.

This is explained in the [developer Apple's IAP overview](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) you referenced:

> ### Consumable
>
> Users can purchase different types of consumables, such as lives or gems in a game, to further their progress through an app. Consumable in-app purchases are used once, are depleted, and can be purchased again.
>
> ### Non-Consumable
>
> Users can purchase non-consumable, premium features within an app. Non-consumables are purchased once and do not expire, such as additional filters in a photo app. Apple can host content associated with your non-consumable in-app purchases.

Based on your comments, I would say you have a Consumable IAP.  You app could be reject for other reasons, though, so this is no guarantee that it will pass App Review.

Comment: OP wants this to be consumable IAP, but this is actually trading app - section 3.1.5

Comment: @bmike Ok, that wasn't indicated in the question when I posted the answer.

Comment: Oh man. You’re right. You can take anything / everything from my post and I’ll delete it.

Comment: @bmike That's fine :-).  If you're ok with leaving both answers, so am I.  I think both are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a currency (the value is consumed outside the app or generated / mined / calculated outside the app) then you need to worry more about section 3.1.5 Goods & Services

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#goods-and-services

These sections restrict outside consumables to prohibit in app purchase, and you would use ApplePay *section 3.1.5(a)* since this is direct trade and commerce. If your currency has any sort of investment or risk, then it’s a trading app *section 3.1.5(b)*.

Only if your currency is consumed and purchased multiple times, would you have to understand if it’s consumed within the app exclusively.

Since you are primary currency and trading, IAP isn’t going to govern your approval or rejection at all.